# Fitnesse: integration with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, fitnesse

I am working on a Selenium WebDriver project, written using the page object pattern.

I wanted to know whether is there any way in which I can integrate FitNesse and Selenium WebDriver project?

I know FitNesse can be used with Selenium IDE, however, I have no idea whether is it possible to use Fitnesse with WebDriver.

Answer (score 1):

You sure can, it's just Java after all. One example of such a project is (my own set of FitNesse fixtures): https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures.

You could use my fixture ([BrowserTest](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki/2.-Slim-Fixtures#browsertest)) to execute the test. Or only use the web driver setup fixture (selenium driver setup), which also also the setup to be overridden in a CI environment, and do your own thing with web driver in a custom fixture.